# Issue with Javascript prototypes

Tags: javascript, function, scope

I'm struggling a bit with JavaScript. I only get the folling code working if i call the init function inside another function. If i call this.init() or that.init() outside the timeout-function, it doesn't work.

```
var App = function() {
    var that = this;       

    // Workaround
    var timeout = setTimeout(function(){            
        that.init();            
    },1);
};

var app = new App();

App.prototype.init = function() {    
    console.log('works');
};
```

Thanks you for your help.

Cheers.

Comment: you can't call init before you've defined it

Comment: Why are you creating an instance before assigning init to the prototype?

Comment: in the case of setTimeout(), it works because your script executes and reads the new prototype.init before it realizes it doesn't exist

Comment: could you explain that? thanks.

Comment: Since you have a constructor *function*, you should not need a `init` method to do the constructor's work. I hope your actual code is just using some common methods from the prototype and does *initialisation* in the constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're assigning the prototype after you instantiate App. Do it before.

```
var App = function() {
    this.init();
};

App.prototype.init = function() {    
    console.log('works');
};

var app = new App();
```